# HTC One X and Android debugging on eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, htc-android

I've been working with android for almost a year now, and I still have this problem.

I can't connect my HTC One X to use on eclipse. It is weird, because it worked one time (only one time). It also works if I connect other devices (a friends phone or tablet).

I've tried everything

- Installing OpenSense SDK from HTC
- Installing HTC Sync Manager
- Installing the old HTC Sync
- Reinstalling Eclipse
- Formating my computer and starting over

Debugging is activated on my phone and also installing apps from unknown sources.
I've gone through many pages of Google with possible solutions but nothing seems to work.

So if the phone works on the computer, but eclipse doesn't find it...

Any ideas what the problem might be? Anyone encountered something similar?

I know his is a bit of a specific problem, but I've tried everything...

Or could it be that the phone is faulty? But then why did it work one time?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: BTW, forgot to mention that HTC Sync Manager doesn't detect the phone either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what i did:

1. Deactivated firewall
2. Reinstalled HTC Sync Manager and HTC drivers
3. Connect phone
4. Go into Device Manager
5. Find android on the list (In mine there were 2), right click and update hardware.
6. Find HTC on the list
7. Update drivers
8. Choose manual
9. Find HTC Sync Managers driver folder
10. Install all drivers manually

Then it finally worked.

Comment: a small note. It happened again after I updated HTC Sync Manager. It doesn't matter in what order you do steps 5-9.

Answer (score 0):

try restarting the server from the command prompt
adb kill-server
adb start-server and see if it is still not getting detected.

Comment: I tried killing and restarting the adb process. Still no luck

Comment: Check to see if you have two versions of adb installed. Eclipse installs one and perhaps HTC Sync installed another. They might be different versions. You'll have to do some path trickery to get both apps to use the same version of adb. Also check and remove Android Studio If you have installed.

Comment: What do you mean? Should I replace the HTC adb with the eclipse one or the other way around?